# Can I use NFC to connect to my Bluetooth headset?

Tags: 8.0, bluetooth, nfc

I have recently upgraded from a Nokia Lumia 800 to a Nokia Lumia 925, which has NFC.

I use a [Plantronics BackBeat 903+ stereo Bluetooth headset](http://www.plantronics.com/uk/product/backbeat-903-plus) (which has excellent sound quality and battery life, by the way).

I would like to attach a small NFC tag to the headset to make it into an 'accessory', like other Bluetooth/NFC devices that are available through Nokia.  Is this possible?

I would like to use the NFC tag to turn on Bluetooth and automatically connect to the headset (preferably overriding the Bluetooth connection to my laptop, of that is possible).

I also want to know what the options are for disabling Bluetooth, again using NFC.  Are there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately WP8 provides very limited support for custom NFC tags. You can use [Nokia NFC Writer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-nfc-writer/709e64e0-5849-4ce4-b252-b7b252aefacf) to create a tag that will take you to the Bluetooth settings screen, but that's about it. You'll still have to manually turn Bluetooth on/off and pair devices.

Comment: Now that I have some tags I have realised that.  I cannot even open apps that are not already preset in the NFC apps I have tried.  Settings cannot be changed (there is only the ability to take you to the settings page) and you need to allow execution of every tag.  It's all very disappointing.  I can't see why one can't make 'secure' tags that can only be executed by your own phone.

Comment: You can open any app if you have its id there is a launch app tag in NFC. examples can be found on codeplex .https://ndef.codeplex.com/

Comment: @caschw: Yes, I have managed to do that now using an app called `NFC interactor`.  I still have to allow execution, but at least I can use NFC tags to open any app now.  I've put an NFC tag on my oven which opens an egg timer app.

Comment: It would be great if it was possible to write digitally signed tags that only your own phone can open, with access to changing settings and with no confirmation dialogue.

Comment: There is a uservoice request for remembering which tags you've trusted. Its been my experience that they listen closely to the uservoice requests. There is a good chance this could come in an update or next phone version. http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3592420-checkbox-to-trust-nfc-stickers